# Has anyone got Error when using Google pagespeed test TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

When I tried to test for speed at our site, I got the error below. Not sure what wrong. I tried other service like pingdom to check and the site load fine. Hope someone can lend an insight. Site link: https://www.insperity.com/blog/calling-in-sick-2/

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        at DetailsRenderer._renderTable (labreport_js.js:77)
        at DetailsRenderer.render (labreport_js.js:71)
        at PerformanceCategoryRenderer.populateAuditValues (labreport_js.js:87)
        at PerformanceCategoryRenderer._renderOpportunity (labreport_js.js:119)
        at labreport_js.js:125
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at PerformanceCategoryRenderer.render (labreport_js.js:125)
        at prepareLabData (labreport_js.js:148)
        at In (www.gstatic.com/pagespeed/insights/76/js/lightsights-en.js:332)
        at Hn.f.b (www.gstatic.com/pagespeed/insights/76/js/lightsights-en.js:328)
    (anonymous) @ www.gstatic.com/pagespeed/insights/76/js/lightsights-en.js:344
```

Comment: Could you confirm a couple of things. 1. Are you using the API, the PSI page (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), Developer tools audit or a local copy of Light House running on your own server? 2. Are you getting this error across the site or only on the page you linked (as that page returns a 404 header so will not scan anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the PageSpeed Insights frontend. It was fixed soon after.

Details: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/10414#issuecomment-597235264

Answer (score 1):

I'll chime in to say that I'm getting "There was a problem with the request. Please try again later." on the PageSpeed Insights page.

But also the "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error in Lighthouse.

I tested it on several sites other than my own and they all come back with the same error message.